# Openshift 4 - CRC - ImagePullBackOff: cannot access local docker daemon to pull image, as it's using HTTP and not HTTPS

Tags: docker, openshift

I am using CRC in my local machine and when I deploy with ansible, I see pods in `ImagePullBackOff` status, because it cannot pull the image. The image is named "some-interal-regsitry:5000/my-image` but actually the image is in local docker daemon. It's local so using HTTP and not safe.

How can I change the settings of Openshift to allow local docker daemon pulling?

Answer (score 0):

Open CRC local page http://console-openshift-console.apps-crc.testing, find in left menubar, "Home" - "Overview", find in right view, "Details" - "View settings",  top tabs, "Configurations", scroll down to "Image", enter, top tab, "YAML", add this part under "spec".

```
spec:
  additionalTrustedCA:
    name: registry-certs
  registrySources:
    insecureRegistries:
      - 'some-interal-regsitry:5000'
```

So HTTP is not blocked anymore.

And you need to add the similar into `/etc/docker/daemon.json` so it would be like:

```json
{
 "bip": "xxxxx",
 "fixed-cidr": "xxxxx",
 "mtu": 1400,
 "dns": ["xxxx", "xxxx", "xxxx"],
 "insecure-registries" : [ "some-interal-regsitry:5000"]
}
```